# Apachi poi for downloading the excel returning empty file exception having zero bytes

Tags: java-8, apache-poi, excel-2010

-------my service code--------

```
public File downloadExcelByDraw(Integer qeiMasterId, String fileName, NMTCService nmtcService) throws Exception {

        this.nmtcService = nmtcService;
        File file = null;
        Qei qeiDetails = nmtcService.getQeiDetail(qeiMasterId);
        log.info("Inside downloadExcelByDraw: " + qeiMasterId);
        file = new File(fileName);
        if(!file.exists()) {
            boolean fileCreated = file.createNewFile();
        }
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
//here it throws empty file exception having zero bytes.
                Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);) {
            log.info("Inside downloadExcelByDraw: Excel Template Name:: " + ExcelConstants.TEMPLATE_EXCEL.getName());

            Sheet templateSheet = workbook.getSheet(ExcelConstants.TEMPLATE_SHEET_NAME.getName());
            fis.close();
            if (qeiDetails != null) {
                String sheetName = ExcelConstants.SHEET_NAME_PREFIX.getName();
                try {
                    super.cloneSheet(templateSheet, sheetName);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("Error in downloadExcelByDraw() :" + e.getStackTrace());
                }
            }
            workbook.removeSheetAt(workbook.getSheetIndex(templateSheet));

            for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
                log.info("sheet index:" + i + ", sheet name: " + sheet.getSheetName());
                ExcelDataProvider excelDataProvider = new ExcelDataProvider(qeiDetails);
                fillNamedRanges(ExcelConstants.getQeiMappings(), excelDataProvider, sheet);
            }

            // file creation changed for file creation
        //  log.info("Inside downloadExcelByDraw:filePath:: " + filePath);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            workbook.write(fos);
            workbook.close();
            log.info("Inside downloadExcelByDraw:fileCreated:: " + file);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error in downloadExcelByDraw() :" + e.getMessage());
        }

        return file;
    }
```

Comment: This is while downloading the excel.

Comment: Are you trying to create a brand new Excel file, or open an existing file?

Comment: brand new excel file for downloading which reads data of UI

Comment: If it's a brand new file, you can't open it if it isn't there! Just create a new `XSSFWorkbook` or `HSSFWorkbook` object to begin

Comment: can i modify my try block like this FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)); workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)

Comment: fileName => "20.xlsx" which comes from UI on click of download button

Comment: The call of `workbook.write(fos);` always writes the **whole** `workbook` to the `fos`. But as you are using `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);` that **appends** the `workbook` to the one which is already contained in `file`. That definitely is wrong. Do `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);` instead.

Comment: If `Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);` throws empty file exception then `fis` points to an empty file. `XSSFWorkbook` cannot be created from an empty file. To create a new `XSSFWorkbook` then `Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();` must be used. So instead of your `if(!file.exists()) { boolean fileCreated = file.createNewFile(); }` do `Workbook workbook = null; if(!file.exists()) { workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); } else { workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file)); }`.